# How to fix cassandra error:111 after Updating the Jdk to 11

Tags: cassandra, jvm, java-11, cassandra-3.0

lately I upgraded my JVM to the newest version 11. However, when I did that, I started having this error.

> Cqlsh output: Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})

I would like to continue on using Jdk 11, however I would like to have cassandra working!

Any suggestion?

Comment: What is your command to connect to the cassandra? Do you pass the hostname with it?

Comment: cqlsh -u username - p password

Comment: Adding hostname might help `cqlsh hostname -u username - p password`

Comment: Worth noting, that Cassandra 3.x requires Java 8.  Java 11 will not work.